Deej macro buttons f-key issues
My deej mixer is running on an Arduino Pro Micro, it has 4 faders and 8 macro buttons, one of which doesn't work, and one other switches between media keys and f-keys modes. The problem that I'm having is that in f-keys mode it just types letters (button 1 is h, button 2 is i, etc.) but all the media keys work fine. I've already tried asking chatgpt and I still haven't been able to get it fixed. I'm still very new to C++ and the Arduino platform in general.
Code:
#include <HID-Project.h>  // For media key support

// Slider definitions
const int NUM_SLIDERS = 4;
const int analogInputs[NUM_SLIDERS] = { A0, A1, A2, A3 };
int analogSliderValues[NUM_SLIDERS];

// Button definitions
#define BUTTON_PIN1 3
#define BUTTON_PIN2 10
#define BUTTON_PIN3 6
#define BUTTON_PIN4 16
#define BUTTON_PIN5 7  // Mode toggle button now
#define BUTTON_PIN6 14
#define BUTTON_PIN7 4
#define BUTTON_PIN8 15

const uint8_t NumButtons = 8;
const uint8_t ledPin = 17;

// Toggle button for switching modes
const uint8_t toggleButtonPin = 7; // Changed to Button 5 (Pin 7)
bool mode = 0; // 0 = Function Keys (F13-F20), 1 = Media Control Keys
bool lastToggleState = HIGH;

// Define function keys (F13-F20)
#define BUTTON_KEY1 KEY_F13
#define BUTTON_KEY2 KEY_F14
#define BUTTON_KEY3 KEY_F15
#define BUTTON_KEY4 KEY_F16
#define BUTTON_KEY5 KEY_F17
#define BUTTON_KEY6 KEY_F18
#define BUTTON_KEY7 KEY_F19
#define BUTTON_KEY8 KEY_F20

// Media key definitions (without volume control keys)
const int mediaKeys[8] = {
  MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE,
  MEDIA_STOP,
  MEDIA_PREVIOUS,
  MEDIA_NEXT,
};

// Button helper class for handling press/release and debouncing
class button {
  public:
    const uint8_t pin;

    button(uint8_t p) : pin(p) {}

    // Overload the press method to handle both function keys and media keys
    void press(boolean state, uint8_t key) {
      if (state == pressed || (millis() - lastPressed <= debounceTime)) {
        return;
      }

      lastPressed = millis();

      if (state) {
        if (key >= KEY_F13 && key <= KEY_F20) {
          Keyboard.press(key);  // Function keys (F13-F20)
        } else {
          Consumer.write(key);  // Media keys
        }
      } else {
        if (key >= KEY_F13 && key <= KEY_F20) {
          Keyboard.release(key);  // Release function keys (F13-F20)
        } else {
          Consumer.write(0);    // Release media keys
        }
      }
      pressed = state;
    }

    void update(uint8_t buttonIndex) {
      bool currentState = !digitalRead(pin);
      if (mode == 0) {
        // Use the correct function key based on the button index
        switch (buttonIndex) {
          case 0: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY1); break;
          case 1: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY2); break;
          case 2: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY3); break;
          case 3: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY4); break;
          case 4: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY5); break;
          case 5: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY6); break;
          case 6: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY7); break;
          case 7: press(currentState, BUTTON_KEY8); break;
        }
      } else {
        press(currentState, mediaKeys[buttonIndex]); // Media keys
      }
    }

  private:
    const unsigned long debounceTime = 30;
    unsigned long lastPressed = 0;
    boolean pressed = 0;
};

// Button objects, organized in array
button buttons[] = {
  button(BUTTON_PIN1),
  button(BUTTON_PIN2),
  button(BUTTON_PIN3),
  button(BUTTON_PIN4),
  button(BUTTON_PIN5),  // Mode toggle on Button 5 (Pin 7)
  button(BUTTON_PIN6),
  button(BUTTON_PIN7),
  button(BUTTON_PIN8)
};

void setup() {
  // Slider setup
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SLIDERS; i++) {
    pinMode(analogInputs[i], INPUT);
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Safety check. Ground pin #1 (RX) to cancel keyboard inputs.
  pinMode(1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  if (!digitalRead(1)) {
    failsafe();
  }

  // Set LEDs Off. Active low.
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  TXLED0;

  for (int i = 0; i < NumButtons; i++) {
    pinMode(buttons[i].pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  }

  // Toggle button setup
  pinMode(toggleButtonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Start the HID-Project library for media keys
  Keyboard.begin();
  Consumer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Check for mode toggle button press (Button 5, Pin 7)
  if (digitalRead(toggleButtonPin) == LOW && lastToggleState == HIGH) {
    mode = !mode; // Toggle the mode
    delay(300);   // Debounce delay to avoid toggling too quickly
  }
  lastToggleState = digitalRead(toggleButtonPin);

  // Update and send slider values
  updateSliderValues();
  sendSliderValues();

  // Check the other buttons for keypresses, skipping button 5
  for (int i = 0; i < NumButtons; i++) {
    // Skip button 5 (toggle button)
    if (i != 4) {  // Button 5 is at index 4 in the array
      buttons[i].update(i);
    }
  }

  delay(10);
}

void updateSliderValues() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SLIDERS; i++) {
    analogSliderValues[i] = analogRead(analogInputs[i]);
  }
}

void sendSliderValues() {
  String builtString = String("");

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SLIDERS; i++) {
    builtString += String((int)analogSliderValues[i]);

    if (i < NUM_SLIDERS - 1) {
      builtString += String("|");
    }
  }

  Serial.println(builtString);
}

void failsafe() {
  for (;;) {} // Just going to hang out here for awhile :D
}

It should be pressing keys f13-f20 when on the macro button mode but just types letters.
Any help is appreciated!
